# Split url string with multiple delimiters and into multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to parse the url query string in SQL Server to multiple columns as follows with the following result:

```
plants=indoor,succulents&locations=ca,co,az&priceupto=100
```

Desired result:

[image: Result]

How do I go about it? Any idea would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to stack overflow! Your problem got a little more complicated after you added the screenshot. For future reference, include the desired results when you post so as to avoid people working hard to providing an answer you're not looking for [/soapbox].

Anyhow, here's how you can handle this using `SPLIT_STRING` note my comments.

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(8000) = 'plants=indoor,succulents&locations=ca,co,az&priceupto=100';

WITH split AS 
(
  SELECT      s2.[value], f.Attrib
  FROM        STRING_SPLIT(@string,'&')                     AS s1
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('=',s1.[value])))           AS dd(Idx)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(s1.[value],0,dd.Idx),
                      SUBSTRING(s1.[value],dd.Idx+1,8000))) AS f(Attrib,Txt)
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(f.Txt,',')                       AS s2
)
SELECT 
  Plant      = pl.[value],  
  [Location] = lo.[value],
    Priceupto  = pr.[value]
FROM       split AS pl
CROSS JOIN split AS lo
CROSS JOIN split AS pr
WHERE      pl.Attrib = 'plants'
AND        lo.Attrib = 'locations'
AND        pr.Attrib = 'priceupto';
--ORDER BY   1,2,3 -- likely not required but returns items in the requested order if needed
```

FYI - for future reference you could (by adding 4 spaces ahead of each line) say, "Here's the output I'm looking for:"

```
Plant         Location  Priceupto
------------- --------- ------------
indoor        ca        100
succulents    ca        100
indoor        co        100
succulents    co        100
indoor        az        100
succulents    az        100
```

This works much better than a screenshot because we can copy/paste the values.

Comment: Thanks so much Alan! Sorry for being a noob..will take note in the future..I'll try this out :-)

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Being able to post good questions ("good" as in, it includes every thing people need to give you a quality answer fast) - this is an easy skill to acquire and is a great tool to have in your toolbox. Note these two articles - https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/forum-etiquette-how-to-post-datacode-on-a-forum-to-get-the-best-help   

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/how-to-post-performance-problems-1

Comment: Also (I'm not saying this for me BTW) - it's always good to up-vote the answers you like and mark one as "the answer" if it solves your problem - people like that and will be more enthusiastic to help you in the future ;)

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler to split over multiple rows; splitting over multiple columns is tedious: you need to know beforehand the maximum number of parameters (columns) that you expect just to write the query (otherwise, you need dynamic SQL).

Here is a simple solution that splits over rows, using `string_split()`; note that there is no possible ordnality with this function (ie no guarantee in which order rows will be generated).

```
select t.url original_url, value param_value
from mytable t
cross apply string_split(t.url, '&')
```

This assumes that the url is stored in column `url` of table `mytable`.

If you want to put the parameter name and its value in two different columns, you can use string functions:

```
select 
    t.url original_url, 
    left(value, charindex('=', value) - 1) param,
    right(value, len(value) - charindex('=', value)) val
from mytable t
cross apply string_split(t.url, '&')
```

Comment: Thanks GMB, that's what I reckon too. there are too many possible parameters.. I'll try your suggestion. thanks heaps! :-)

Comment: @QueenSerenity - not your fault but the OP clarified requirement. What you posted wont work for the updated problem

Answer (score 0):

You might try something along this:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(1000)='plants=indoor,succulents&locations=ca,co,az&priceupto=100';

SELECT CAST('<x content="' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@str,',','</y><y>'),'=','"><y>'),'&','</y></x><x content="') + '"</y></x>' AS XML);
```

We use some replacements to transform your string into XML

```
<x content="plants">
  <y>indoor</y>
  <y>succulents</y>
</x>
<x content="locations">
  <y>ca</y>
  <y>co</y>
  <y>az</y>
</x>
<x content="priceupto">
  <y>100"</y>
</x>
```

### How to use this

Test this as your final query

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(1000)='plants=indoor,succulents&locations=ca,co,az&priceupto=100';

SELECT A.plants.value('text()[1]','varchar(100)') AS Plant
      ,B.locations.value('text()[1]','varchar(100)') AS [Location]
      ,C.priceupto.value('text()[1]','varchar(100)') AS PriceUpTo
FROM (VALUES(CAST('<x content="' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@str,',','</y><y>'),'=','"><y>'),'&','</y></x><x content="') + '</y></x>' AS XML))) The(StringAsXml)
CROSS APPLY The.StringAsXml.nodes('/x[@content="plants"]/y') A(plants)
CROSS APPLY The.StringAsXml.nodes('/x[@content="locations"]/y') B(locations)
CROSS APPLY The.StringAsXml.nodes('/x[@content="priceupto"]/y') C(priceupto);
```

The result

```
Plant   Location    PriceUpTo
indoor      ca      100
indoor      co      100
indoor      az      100
succulents  ca      100
succulents  co      100
succulents  az      100
```

The idea in short:

Using `CROSS APPLY` with `.nodes()` will add a list of each value below the given XPath.
This will create an *each-with-each* result, similar to `CROSS JOIN`ing sets.

if your `priceupto` is one single element in all your cases, this can be simplified of course, with the same result:

```
SELECT A.plants.value('text()[1]','varchar(100)') AS Plant
      ,B.locations.value('text()[1]','varchar(100)') AS [Location]
      ,the.StringAsXml.value('(/x[@content="priceupto"]/y/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS PriceUpTo
FROM (VALUES(CAST('<x content="' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@str,',','</y><y>'),'=','"><y>'),'&','</y></x><x content="') + '</y></x>' AS XML))) The(StringAsXml)
CROSS APPLY The.StringAsXml.nodes('/x[@content="plants"]/y') A(plants)
CROSS APPLY The.StringAsXml.nodes('/x[@content="locations"]/y') B(locations)
```